# Old version of image shows up in iPhone Simulator even after removing the app cache

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I can't figure this one out.  I've got an iPhone-only app with an image -- location.png -- that has had two versions since starting the application.  When I build the app for my actual phone, I get the new version of the image.  When I build it for the simulator, however, the old version of the image shows up.

I've dealt with this type of thing before, and usually how I resolve it is by removing the entire folder containing the application and cache from `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/X.X/Applications/`.  That has always worked up until now, when I'm still getting that pesky image after deleting that cache multiple times.  It's not really a huge deal, I'd just like to know how to get rid of it for my own sanity (or in case I need to do it again in the future in a case where it matters more).  Any ideas?

Comment: maybe try cleaning and deleting the app from the simulator as well as deleting the folder?

Comment: UGH!  I feel silly.  Clean worked like a charm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I performed a Clean (Product -> Clean in Xcode) as per [Msencenb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/482255/msencenb)'s advice, and that resolved the issue.  I'll leave the question up in case someone else has the same problem.